# Python, getting to count down on attempts

Tags: python-2.7

I am a beginer at Python, I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

What I am trying to do is get this quiz first ask you the time you want to try and get the correct answer then stop after you have reached that attept count down.  Any help or input would be greatly appreciated. I am also try to figure out how to fill in blanks like this

`fill_in_blanks = ["__1__", "__2__", "__3__", "__4__", "__5__"]`

here is my code

```
fill_in_blanks = ["__1__", "__2__", "__3__", "__4__", "__5__"]

# Question and answer for each level of play
easy_level = "The answers will consist of female or male. My sister is a __1__. My father " \
         "is a __2__. My mother is a __3__.  My grandmother is a __4__.  " \
         "My grandfather is a __5__."
easy_answers = ["female", "male", "female", "female", "male"]       #allowing the user to select the level of play
        def select_level():
            print "\nPlease choose a level. You can choose easy, medium, hard, or     bonus"
            choice = raw_input("Enter your level now: ")
            return choice


def select_attempt():
    attempt = raw_input("Please chose the number of your attempts 1 to 5. ")
    return attempt


def countdown(attempt):
     while attempt > 0:
        attempt = attempt - 1
        return attempt


# getting the correct level quiz and answers
def get_quiz(level):
    if level=="easy":
        return (easy_level, easy_answers)
    if level=="medium":
        return (medium_level, medium_answers)
    if level=="hard":
        return (hard_level, hard_answers)
    if level=="bonus":
        return (bonus_level, bonus_answers)


# checking the users answers vs the levels answers
def play_game(questions, answers, attempt, fill_in_blanks):
    while attempt > 0:
        print questions
        for i in range(0, 5):
           user_input = raw_input("\n Please type the answer for blank " + str(i+1) + ".")
            print "user input is " + user_input
            print "the answer is " + answers[i]
            if user_input == answers[i]:
                i += i + 1
                print ("Awesome!")
                print questions
            if user_input != answers[i]:
                attempt = attempt - 1
                user_input = raw_input("\n Oops! Incorrect! Please type the answer for blank " + str(i+1) + ".")
            return "Have a great day!"

# play game
def start_game():
    level = select_level()
    attempt = select_attempt()
    answers, questions = get_quiz(level)
    play_game(answers, questions, attempt, fill_in_blanks)


start_game()
```

Comment: I guess I am missing where the indention is wrong

Comment: the function named select_level

Comment: okay i fixed that but it still giving me an error when checking the attempt...                     line 91, in play_game
    attempt = attempt - 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: I want it to count down on the attempts that the user selects

Comment: What is attempt? I don't see a global variable

Comment: def select_attempt():
    attempt = raw_input("Please chose the number of your attempts 1 to 5. ")
    return attempt


def countdown(attempt):
    while attempt > 0:
        attempt = attempt - 1
        return attempt

Comment: Use `int(raw_input("Prompt"))`

Comment: def select_attempt():
        attempt = raw_input("Please chose the number of your attempts 1 to 5. ")
        return attempt


    def countdown(attempt):
        while attempt > 0:
            attempt = attempt - 1
            return attempt
    # checking the users answers vs the levels answers
    def play_game(questions, answers, attempt, fill_in_blanks):
        while attempt > 0: